# Adding onclick property to an ImageButton in the parent page from JS function called from button inside page loaded into FancyBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, onclick, fancybox

I am using  ["FancyBox"](http://fancybox.net/home) in ASP.NET User Control (inside a Content Page).
I want that a click(client side click) on a button 'placed on the page loaded into the FancyBox ,will call a JavaScript function, and in that function I want to enable a ImageButton contained in the parent page(The page that opened the FancyBox modal dialog)and Dynamically add 'onclick'
property to it.

In the code file of the form that contains the ImageButton I added an attribute so I can easily select it using JQuery

ibtnDeleteImage.Attributes.Add("serverID", "ibtnDeleteImage");

Here is the function used to add the onclick property to the ImageButton

```
 function addOnclick() {

   //Get ref to the delete article thumbnail image button
   var $ibtnDeleteThumbImage = $("input[serverId='ibtnDeleteImage']", window.parent.document);

   //Enable the image button
   $ibtnDeleteThumbImage.removeAttr("disabled");

   //Add  onclick property to the ImageButton assign it an  event handler and avoid post back to the server
   $ibtnDeleteThumbImage[0].onclick = function() { deleteThumbnailImage(); return false; };

    }
```

Here is the event handler :

```
function deleteThumbnailImage() {
   var dialogMessage = "Are you sure you want \n to delete the article thumbnail";
   if (confirm(dialogMessage)) {
       var $ibtnDeleteThumbImage = $("input[serverId='ibtnDeleteImage']", window.parent.document);
       //Remove the onclick property from the ImageButton
       $ibtnDeleteThumbImage.removeAttr("click");
       //Disable the ImageButton
       $ibtnDeleteThumbImage.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

   }
```

}

I am using the syntax

```
 $ibtnDeleteThumbImage[0].onclick = function() { deleteThumbnailImage(); return false; };
```

And not

```
$ibtnDeleteThumbImage.attr("onclick", "deleteThumbnailImage();return false;");
```

Because of the problem described [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4281)

**My problem** :
This syntax work well in a javascript function called by a button contained page loaded  in a regular Iframe but not in one contained in page loaded into FancyBox.
(The onclick property is not added to the ImageButton and there is a postback to the server)

Does anyone know what is the problem and  what is the solution to it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That could be a cross scripting issue.

In your addOnClick function, you could do something like this

```
$("input[serverId='ibtnDeleteImage']").click(function() { 
    // perform delete logic here
}).removeAttr("disabled");
```